# Question deleted; link still appears

Tags: bug, ios-app

- App Version: 1.6.0.10
- Device: iPad Air 2 (Cellular)
- OS Version: Version 10.0.2 (Build 14A456)

I deleted my recent bug report because I learned it was duplicate.  Next day (or maybe even longer) there is still a link to it on the app "feed."  The link doesn't work, of course, but the feed-building code should not create it.